# Python, Selenium and Chrome - How do can I detect the end of a page with dynamically generated content?

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping

I have gone through existing questions and google results of a similar nature, every solution posed has not worked for me within the particular website I am currently scraping.

https://dutchie.com/embedded-menu/revolutionary-clinics-somerville/menu

I am sending page down keys to the body element, which loads each item to be scraped. I have two issues with this, first I am unable to detect when the scrolling has stopped. Second, I have to manually click the browser window as it opens to allow the keys to be sent. I am not sure how to mimic this same focus giving behavior via code.

```
elem = driver.find_element_by_tag_name("body")
elem.send_keys(Keys.PAGE_DOWN)
```

I have tried the following, in many different iterations and the number printed never charged regardless of how far down the page I am or if I used innerHeight, or body instead of documentElement.

```
height = driver.execute_script("return document.documentElement.scrollHeight")
```

If I attempt to scroll down the page using a similar approach, this page does not move.

```
driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);")
```

I am unsure if this has to do with iframes or if I am simply misunderstanding the best approach.

Still have been unable to find a way to reliably detect the end of the page.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

After importing the required imports

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```

you can validate the page button is reached when the following element is visible:

```
element = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
        EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//p[contains(text(),'License')]"))
```

As about the second issue, try clicking on the following element with Selenium:

```
driver.find_element_by_id("products-container").click
```

I have no environment to debug this, but I guess this will work

Comment: For the second issue, I get this error message.
`AttributeError: 'WebDriver' object has no attribute 'find_element_by_tag_id'`
I modified it slightly in an attempt to use a css selector and it gives me:
`AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'click'`

Comment: Sure, it was my typo. It should be `find_element_by_id`. I'm sorry

Comment: With updated code the error message is gone, but the page still does not scroll unless I manually click into the browser when it loads.

Comment: That strange....
I totally have no python on my PC now to debug this, but it sounds strange

Comment: I will keep plugging away, could you clarify the first part of your commet about finding the bottom of the page? Where in the source code should I expect to see license?

Comment: Sure. If you scroll till the page bottom appears you will see `License: RMD-405R` text there. This element is I'm looking for

Comment: One last thing, my end goal is to use this on multiple sites structured similarly to the above link. Not all of them have that license text in the footer, is there a potential solution that would not rely on the license text? Thanks.

Comment: Sure. You have to pass some locator to the function. Each time the locator will be different according to the specific page you are working with. In this specific case the locator is `(By.XPATH, "//p[contains(text(),'License')]")`
Please upvote if I could help you

Comment: Right. But not all pages have something at the end of the page that would allow me to use this unless there is a way to know if an element is the last element which I have been unable to figure out.

Comment: Wait! The button is initially on the bottom and not visible? if so you definitely have to scroll to this element to bring it into the view and only after that to click on it!